# how to speed up the algorithm about boolean

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, boolean

If I have a very large piece of data, and I want to find out some specific elements and convert them from bool to number. For example, I want to find whether the element is in the interval (0.3,0.4), and convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`.

```
i=np.random.rand(1000,1000,1000)
j=((0.3<i)*(i<0.4))*1
```

Does `j=((0.3<i)&(i<0.4))*1` work the same as the expression above?

I know bool*bool is time-consuming and exploit a huge memory, and so is bool convert to number. Then how can I seed up the algorithm and save memory? Is there a way to evaluate `0.3<i<0.4` quickly?

Comment: If you want to know whether it works the same way, don't ask us: ask Python.  Run a set of tests.  The Python run-time system is the ultimate authority, after all, and we're not a testing service.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [numexpr](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)? You could always write a C-extension to do it memory-efficiently...

Comment: C-extension? Can I control how much the memory can be used?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for boolean arrays `&` and `*` are identical because both are only `True` if both operands are `True`, otherwise `False`.

You already found out that each operation creates a temporary array (although newer NumPy versions might be optimized in that respect), so you have one temporary boolean array for each `<`, one for the `*` or the `&` and then you create an integer array with the `* 1`. Without using additional libraries you can't avoid that. NumPy is fast because it does the loops in C but that means you have to deal with temporary arrays.

But with additional libraries you actually can speed that up and make it more memory-efficient.

### Numba:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def numba_func(arr, lower, upper):
    res = np.zeros(arr.size, dtype=np.int8)
    arr_raveled = arr.ravel()
    for idx in range(arr.size):
        res[idx] = lower < arr_raveled[idx] < upper
    return res.reshape(arr.shape)

>>> numba_func(i, 0.3, 0.4)  # sample call
```

### Numexpr

```
import numexpr as ne

ne.evaluate('((0.3<i)&(i<0.4))*1')
```

However numexpr is more of a black-box, you don't control how much memory it needs, but in most cases where you deal with multiple element-wise NumPy operations it's **very fast and much more memory efficient** than NumPy.

### Cython

I'm using IPython magic here. If you don't use IPython or Jupyter you probably need to `cythonize` it yourself.

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

cpdef cnp.int8_t[:] cython_func(double[:] arr, double lower, double upper):
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    cdef cnp.int8_t[:] res = np.empty(len(arr), dtype=np.int8)
    for idx in range(len(arr)):
        res[idx] = lower < arr[idx] < upper
    return res
```

Given that I used 1D-memoryviews here, you need to cast it to an array and reshape it afterwards:

```
np.asarray(cython_func(i.ravel(), 0.3, 0.4)).reshape(i.shape)  # sample call
```

There are probably better ways to get around the `ravel`, `asarray` and `reshape` but those require that you know the dimension of your array.

### Timing

I use a smaller array because I don't have much RAM but you can easily change the numbers:

```
i = np.random.random((1000, 1000, 10))

%timeit numba_func(i, 0.3, 0.4)
52.1 ms ± 3.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit ne.evaluate('((0.3<i)&(i<0.4))*1')
77.1 ms ± 6.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit np.asarray(cython_func(i.ravel(), 0.3, 0.4)).reshape(i.shape)
146 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit ((0.3<i)&(i<0.4))*1
180 ms ± 2.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: will it be more efficient if I do `j=(i<0.4)*1-(i<0.3)*1`? Can the additional libraries (numba, numexpr, cython) vectorize an array to make it more efficient like numpy does?

Comment: It will probably be less efficent because you have 5 temporary arrays then and 3 of them are integers (taking up more space than bools). However, you need to time it or use a memory profiler to find out which optimizations kick in on your system. Numba and cython are more like Python -> C converters, both are capable (as far as I know) of using hardware vectorization but you need to code the loops yourself. Numexpr on the other hand is just a different (more optimized and parallel) backend for NumPy operations, so it uses vectorization and broadcasting by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the expression works the same.  Check it with

```
jmult = ((0.3<i)*(i<0.4))*1
jand  = ((0.3<i)&(i<0.4))*1
jand == jmult
```

Comment: Whoops!  You're working in NumPy, not Python.  No, this won't work for you.